# Two sets of labels on pgfplot bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like another set of hard-coded labels that sit on top, near the bottom (0) of each bar. I.e., like the `nodes near coords` labels, but shifted down towards 0 and with my own custom text. So in the following example, there would be an additional four labels (not shown). Is there an easy way to do that? Thanks!

[image: example]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{sfmath}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=\textwidth,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,axis on top, ymax=100,
ymin=30,
height=8cm,
width=5cm,
enlarge x limits=0.5,
ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
major grid style={draw=white},
axis x line*=left,
ylabel={\%},
xtick=data,
legend cell align=left,
max space between ticks=20pt,
legend style={ at={(0.57,1.05)} ,
                column sep=1ex },
symbolic x coords={label1, label2},
nodes near coords=\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
]
 \addplot[draw=none,fill=blue!40!white] coordinates      {(label1,80.2)      (label2,90.7)   }; 
 \addplot[draw=none,fill=red!40!white] coordinates      {(label1,70)      (label2,80) }; 

\legend{Data1, Data2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works for two data series.  The idea is to add two labels below each x value, one to the left (`anchor=east`) and one to the right (`anchor=west`).  The x position is taken from the `symbolic x coordinates` system, the y coordinate is taken from the `xticklabel cs`, which lies on the x axis.  If we would just put the corresponding `\node` command into the axis environment, it would be clipped away.  The option `\after end axis/.code` allows to specify code to be executed after the clipping.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,axis on top, ymax=100,
ymin=30,
height=8cm,
width=5cm,
enlarge x limits=0.5,
ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
major grid style={draw=white},
axis x line*=left,
ylabel={\%},
xtick=data,
legend cell align=left,
max space between ticks=20pt,
legend style={ at={(0.57,1.05)} ,
                column sep=1ex },
symbolic x coords={label1, label2},
nodes near coords=\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
after end axis/.code={
\node(L1) at (axis cs:label1,1) {};
\node(L2) at (axis cs:label2,1) {};
\node(XTL) at (xticklabel cs:0)  {};
\node[anchor=north east] at (L1 |- XTL) {L11};
\node[anchor=north west] at (L1 |- XTL) {L12};
\node[anchor=north east] at (L2 |- XTL) {L21};
\node[anchor=north west] at (L2 |- XTL) {L22};
},
]
 \addplot[draw=none,fill=blue!40!white] coordinates      {(label1,80.2)      (label2,90.7)   }; 
 \addplot[draw=none,fill=red!40!white] coordinates      {(label1,70)      (label2,80) }; 

\legend{Data1, Data2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**EDIT: Labels above x axis**

I overread that you wanted to have the labels above the xaxis.  This can be achieved with the following change to the above code:

```
after end axis/.code={
\node(L1) at (axis cs:label1,1) {};
\node(L2) at (axis cs:label2,1) {};
\node(XTL) at (xticklabel* cs:0)  {};
\node[anchor=south east] at (L1 |- XTL) {\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize L11}};
\node[anchor=south west] at (L1 |- XTL) {\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize L12}};
\node[anchor=south east] at (L2 |- XTL) {\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize L21}};
\node[anchor=south west] at (L2 |- XTL) {\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize L22}};
},
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jarauh! How would you generalise this to more than two datasets?